# AD/LDAP and PHP Password Policy Enforcement

Tags: php, passwords, ldap, password-policy

I am a newbie in this field..

Is there any password policy in AD/LDAP? Is it possible for me to add my own policy in there using php? If yes, please tell me how or give me some reference to learn more about it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in AD there are Password Settings Objects (PSOs) that can be used for password policy enforcement. You can create them in PHP, but there is quite a bit of work that goes into that.

- They all have an objectClass value of `msDS-PasswordSettings`
- They must be placed in the passwords settings container (ie `'CN=Password Settings Container,CN=System,dc=domain,dc=com`
- There are quite a few required attributes that need to be set to create one.

There's actually a built-in method for creating PSOs in the [LdapTools](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools) library. There's documentation on it [here](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools/blob/master/docs/en/tutorials/Creating-AD-Password-Settings-Objects.md).

Some general information on PSOs on Microsoft's site: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842%28v=ws.10%29.aspx